# How to achieve line spacing when using custom font

Tags: fonts, xetex, line-spacing

I would like to be able to determine the line spacing in the following example:

[image]

The line spacing is clearly not good. My TeX code looks as follows:

```
\HRule \\[0.5cm]
{ \fontsize{30pt}{10cm}\neosanslight This is some random text with not enough line spacing} 
\vspace{0.3cm}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
```

I thought that the second argument to the `\fontsize` command would determine the line spacing, but no matter what I set it to, it does not change.

My definition of the custom font looks like this:

```
\newfontfamily{\neosanslight}[
UprightFont={* Light},
ItalicFont={* Light Italic}]{NeoSans}
```

I am using XeLaTeX to be able to use the custom font.

Does anyone have suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a well known problem: the paragraph you're typesetting uses the baseline skip current *outside* the braces, because the end of paragraph is seen after the closing brace, which ends the scope of the `\fontsize` declaration. Just add `\par` before the closing brace:

```
\HRule \\[0.5cm]
{\fontsize{30pt}{10cm}\neosanslight This is some random text with not enough line spacing\par} 
\vspace{0.3cm}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
```